# How to add validation in graphql resolver used to create a new node(Neo4j) assigning an existing relationship too?

Tags: neo4j, graphql-js

In my neo4j(3.2 version), I already have nodes for labels "Player","Team" and "Position". The relation between each of them is:

**(p:Player)-[:Currently_In]->(t:Team), (p:Player)-[:In_Position]->(a:Position)**

[image: data model]

Now,I want to add a new player to an existing Team for a new position (using graphql resolver). However, he should not be added if the position already exists.

**For e.g. My dB already has "Messi" (p:Player) in "Barca" (t:Team) and in position "Central Forward".So, now if I wish to add any new player "John" in position "Central Forward" for the same team "Barca", he should not be added.**

How can I achieve this in graphql resolver?

here is my **schema** sample:

```
//Schema.js
AddPlayer(label: String!,  PlayerID: String, TeamID: String, PositionID: String): Player
```

Here is Resolver sample:

```
AddPlayer(_, args) {
  let session = driver.session();

        var query = `
                            MERGE(p:Player{PlayerID: $PlayerID })
                            MERGE(t:Team{TeamID: $TeamID})
                            MERGE(a:Position{PositionID: $PositionID})

                            MERGE(p)-[:Currently_In]->(t)  
                            MERGE(p)-[:In_Position]->(a)  


                               ON create set p.label={label}
                          RETURN p;`

  return session.run(query, args)
    .then(result => {
      return result.records[0].get("p").properties
    })
}
```

I couldn't find anything that would be helpful to validate by graphql or neo4j. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simple test:

```
MERGE(t:Team{TeamID: $TeamID})
MERGE(a:Position{PositionID: $PositionID})
WITH t, a
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)<-[:In_Position]-(PT:Player)-[:Currently_In]->(t)
WITH a, t, count(PT) as playersCount
     WHERE playersCount <= 3
       MERGE(p:Player{PlayerID: $PlayerID })
       MERGE(p)-[:Currently_In]->(t) ON create set p.label={label} 
       MERGE(p)-[:In_Position]->(a)  
RETURN p;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So, now if I wish to add at most 3 players in 1 same position for a same team,then what should I do for that case ? I tried using count(PT)=3 but it did not work. Any suggestions !!   For e.g Current query would only let one player to be added for "Forward" post for 1 team. How can I limit the query to allow 3 players for same position?

Comment: @CodeReactor Sorry, I do not understand what you want to get. Try to explain better.

Comment: I want to add "John","Doe" and "Jane" player for the same position "Forward" for a same team. But after adding these 3, the 4th player should not be added for same position "Forward" for the same team. Thanks again for your cooperation !

Comment: Thanks but I am getting an error after adding the updated code. It says "Variable PT is not defined" (in GraphiQL). What should I do ?

Comment: Yes, I did not delete this part of the query :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ...You saved my day...Awesome..Have a nice time !!